# Splunk, how to output kv and tables based on templates

Tags: splunk

I have a project needs to extract information from 16 input files, do some manipulation, output to a template file. The template format is something as below: The question is what splunk command I shall use to output a file based on template?

**Template file format:**

```
field1 = $1
field2 = $2
:
:
fieldN=  $N

column1, column2, column3, ...  columnM
$data11, $data21, $data31,  ...  $dataM1


$data1K, $data2K, $data3K,  ...  $dataMK
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no one Splunk command to do that.  Furthermore, Splunk has no concept of "template file".

You can use `outputcsv` to produce the latter ("column1, column2, ...") portion of the output, but I know of no way to also do the first part.